# How can I get a console listing that shows the values of fields from an object IList?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
IList<Question> oldObj = _questionService.GetQuestions(id);
```

The Question class has a field of QuestionId.

Can someone tell me how can I get a console list of all the QuestionIds

Comment: What do you mean by "a console list" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a single string for the `QuestionIDs` separated by `NewLine` using `string.Join` and can output using `Console.WriteLine`

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join
                        (Environment.NewLine, oldObj.Select(r=> r.QuestionId)));
```

For Web application/ ASP.Net:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Join
                        (Environment.NewLine, oldObj.Select(r=> r.QuestionId)));
```

Comment: I tried this but I cannot see anything appear in the "output" window. Is there a different command to get it to show there?

Comment: @SamanthaJ, what kind of application you are targeting isn't it a Console App ?

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine solved my problem :-)